# Get the percentage of values from a column in Panda that are in top n% like 25%, 50% etc or below n%

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a dataframe like this -

[image]

I want columns like this from the table -

[image]

So the final table would be like this -

[image]

How can I calculate these column.

I am having current code in django rest API -

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def sale_prod(request):       
if request.method == 'GET':

    data = sales_products.objects.values()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.groupby(['item_id','item_code'])['amount','quantity'].sum().reset_index()
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    df['amount_per'] = (df.amount / df.amount.sum())*100          # revenue contribution
    df['quantity_per'] = (df.quantity / df.quantity.sum())*100    # unit sold contribution
    df = df.round({'quantity': 0, 'amount':2, 'amount_per':2, 'quantity_per':2})

    main_list = []
    for ind in df.index:

        dict1 = {}
        dict1['item_code'] = df['item_code'][ind]
        dict1['amount'] = df['amount'][ind]
        dict1['quantity'] = df['quantity'][ind]
        dict1['amount_per'] = df['amount_per'][ind]
        dict1['quantity_per'] = df['quantity_per'][ind]
        main_list.append(dict1)

    return Response(main_list)
```

This code gives me the output in the form of dataframe -

[image]

amount_per = percentage contribution of the item by amount

quantity_per = percentage contribution of the item by quantity

Please help me out to find out the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [df.quantile](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) and some basic math.

Presenting these values inside the table has not much value - its 3 more columns times `len(df)` data thats all the same - so I give them as simple statements:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# some data shuffling to see it works on unsorted data
random.seed(42)
data = [[f"product {i+1:3d}",i*10] for i in range(100)]
random.shuffle(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'price']) 

# calculate the quantile series
q25 = df.quantile(.25, numeric_only=True)
q50 = df.quantile(.5, numeric_only=True)
q75 = df.quantile(.75, numeric_only=True)

print (q25, q50, q75, sep="\n\n")

print( f"Bottom 25% of prices are below/equal to {q25.price} thats", end=" ") 
print( f"{len(df[df.price <= q25.price]) / (len(df) / 100)}% of all items")

print( f"Bottom 50% of prices are below/equal to {q50.price} thats", end=" ")
print( f"{len(df[df.price <= q50.price]) / (len(df) / 100)}% of all items")

print( f"Bottom 75% of prices are below/equal to {q75.price} thats", end= " ")
print( f"{len(df[df.price <= q75.price]) / (len(df)/ 100)}% of all items")
```

(Unshuffled) Dataframe looks like

```
           name  price
0   product   1      0
1   product   2     10
2   product   3     20 
..          ...    ...  
97  product  98    970
98  product  99    980
99  product 100    990

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Output:

```
price    247.5
Name: 0.25, dtype: float64

price    495.0
Name: 0.5, dtype: float64

price    742.5
Name: 0.75, dtype: float64

Bottom 25% of prices are below/equal to 247.5 thats 25.0% of all items
Bottom 50% of prices are below/equal to 495.0 thats 50.0% of all items
Bottom 75% of prices are below/equal to 742.5 thats 75.0% of all items
```